# Rewrite rule for sub domains is not firing

Tags: c#, .net, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-4

(I've browsed through a ton of links on stack and articles like this on Microsoft http://forums.iis.net/t/1161629.aspx/1  Anything regarding sub-domains on stack either doesn't have an answer or the solution simply doesn't work.  Please keep this in mind before flagging as "duplicate".  I did my homework before asking)

I'm not certain whether or nto this has anything to do with MVC4 or not but here is my rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Apply Sub-Domain as Query String Argument" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="^(.+)$" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(^local[a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="https://local.domain.com{C:2}?cobrand={C:1}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I expect this for a url of `https://subdomain.domain.com` to send this into MVC4 as `https://local.domain.com?cobrand=subdomain` but it isn't firing.

In my MVC application I have a view defined as:

```
<div>
    Cobrand = @HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["cobrand"]
</div>
<div>
    Requested URL = @HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
</div>
<div>
    Path = @HttpContext.Current.Request.Path
</div>
```

With the following output for this requested url https://localdemo1.domain.com :

```
<div>
    Cobrand = 
</div>
<div>
    Requested URL = https://localdemo1.domain.com
</div>
<div>
    Path = /
</div>
```

My desired output is:

```
<div>
    Cobrand = localdemo1
</div>
<div>
    Requested URL = https://local.domain.com?cobrand=localdemo1
</div>
<div>
    Path = /
</div>
```

A note about the site setup:

> The IIS Site has bindings for:
>
> HTTP::
>
> local.domain.com
>
> localdemo1.domain.com
>
> localdemo2.domain.com

HTTPS::443 (No host configuration, can't configure host on 443 but it's configured to allow SSL)

PS:  I tried this without HTTPS and it yields the same results, as not firing at all.

Comment: What if you use `type="Redirect"` instead of `type="Rewrite"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what works for me:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Apply Sub-Domain as Query String Argument" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="^.*$" />
      <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(^local[a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://local.domain.com{R:0}?cobrand={C:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Note that the `match url` as changed (accepting empty values) and that `type="Redirect"` has replaced `type="Rewrite"`.

`{C:2}` doesn't work in this case (I am not able to tell you why...) but you can use `{R:0}` instead.

Comment: Will check out first thing in the AM... I'm about as burned out on this as I could be... Thank you!